# How can I return a reference to the root of the tree

Tags: python, algorithm, binary-tree, depth-first-search

In leetcode problem 669. Trim a Binary Search Tree

I am having trouble returning the correct output. I believe I am trimming the tree correctly, but I am returning None each time and I see this when I walkthrough my code. I do not know how to return the new list starting from the root node.

Here is the question:

Given the root of a binary search tree and the lowest and highest boundaries as low and high, trim the tree so that all its elements lies in [low, high]. Trimming the tree should not change the relative structure of the elements that will remain in the tree (i.e., any node's descendant should remain a descendant). It can be proven that there is a unique answer.

Return the root of the trimmed binary search tree. Note that the root may change depending on the given bounds.

my implementation

```
# Definition for a binary tree node.
# class TreeNode:
#     def __init__(self, val=0, left=None, right=None):
#         self.val = val
#         self.left = left
#         self.right = right

class Solution:
    def update_parent(self, parent):
        left_ancestors = parent.left
        parent = parent.right
        ancestor = parent
        
        while ancestor is not None and ancestor.left is not None:
            ancestor = ancestor.left
            
        if ancestor is not None:
            ancestor.left = left_ancestors
        
        return parent
    
    def trimBST(self, root: Optional[TreeNode], low: int, high: int) -> Optional[TreeNode]:
        if root is None:
            return root
        
        if low <= root.val <= high:
            self.trimBST(root.left, low, high)
            self.trimBST(root.right, low, high)
        else:
            root = self.update_parent(root)
            self.trimBST(root, low, high)
```

My thought process was to update the tree by trimming the current node if the current node does not lie within the bounds `low <= node.val <= high`. I take the right child of that current node and keep a temporary reference of all the current nodes left ancestors. I replace the current node with right child and if the right child has any left children I continue to check for left children until no more and attach the temporary ancestors of the current node we had trimmed to the end of the left path.

I think I am trimming this correctly but my biggest concern is that I am only returning `None` and I understand I am doing this wrong. If I can get a clue as to what I am doing wrong, that would be great!

Answer (score 1):

I think you have the right approach; you are just forgetting to *update* the left and right references with the newly trimmed trees if the root value is in range. If the root value is *out* of range, you won't return it at all, but rather the root of the child that can contain in-range values.

```
def trimBST(self, root: Optional[TreeNode], low: int, high: int) -> Optional[TreeNode]:

    if root is None:
        return root

    root.left = self.trimBST(root.left, low, high)
    root.right = self.trimBST(root.right, low, high)
    
    if low <= root.val <= high:
        return root
    elif root.val < low:
        # The root and the entire left subtree are too small
        return root.right
    else:  # root.val > high
        # The root and the entire right subtree are too big
        return root.left
```

Of course, this can be optimized. If the root node is out of range, there's no point in trimming one subtree or the other, because it can be lopped off immediately. That is, you can defer trimming a subtree until you know it is necessary to do so.

```
def trimBST(self, root: Optional[TreeNode], low: int, high: int) -> Optional[TreeNode]:

    if root is None:
        return root
    
    if low <= root.val <= high:
        root.left = self.trimBST(root.left, low, high)
        root.right = self.trimBST(root.right, low, high)
        return root
    elif root.val < low:
        # The root and the entire left subtree are too small.
        # No need to trim the left subtree; we'll just ignore it
        return self.trimBST(root.right)
    else:  # root.val > high
        # The root and the entire right subtree are too big.
        # No need to trim the right subtree; we'll just ignore it
        return self.trimBST(root.left)
```

Comment: I see. If I find a node out of range where node.val < low then all nodes to the left should be trimmed by definition of a bst. Likewise, if I find a node out of range where node.val > high then right subtree of that node should be trimmed also by definition of a bst. And we make sure to return the root so as we go back up the tree we return only the nodes that satisfy `low <= node.val <= high`